# Is it possible to create the database prior to django running any migration commands?

Tags: django

I spun up a MySQL database but I've noticed I have to manually connect to it and run `CREATE {DB}` and then run my migrations. If I don't the database can't be found. Does django provide some form of utility that lets me run `CREATE {DB}`?

Comment: syncdb might help. It allows creating tables for apps without migrations.

Comment: @ArthurChoate syncdb appears to have been deprecated

Comment: django-admin migrate --run-syncdb, perhaps this?

Comment: @ArthurChoate I tried running `manage.py--run-syncdb` and I ran into `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'mydb'")` which is exactly the problem that I'm trying to solve :\ Seems like I can't create a database unless I manually open a sql shell and run create database